# Sharepoint reusable content type workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, content-type, designer-workflow, reusable

I am having a SharePoint 2010 type designer reusable workflow that is associated to a content type that sends an email when an item is created in a list.

There are multiple sub sites where the list is available and the list is having a content type associated to it.

The workflow shows up in the root site, but not in the sub sites.
Could you please help me?